# Is there a way to search project glossaries in Sparx Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

There doesn't appear to be a way to search project glossaries in Sparx Enterprise Architect using the model search. Is there a way to craft a SQL statement to be able to search the glossary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The glossary is stored in the table `t_glossary`.

Note that the `Meaning` column may contain formatting tags, which can complicate things.

Comment: Thanks. When you say formatted tags, what do you mean? Also I presume the SQL query would look like `SELECT * FROM t_glossary`?

Comment: Yes, if you want to retrieve all entries. As for the tags, the Glossary Detail dialog (where you define glossary entries) allows simple formatting (bold, underline, bullet list, etc) of an entry's meaning. This formatting is stored as tags (<b>, </b>, <i>, </i>, etc) inside the string for the entry, so if you're searching for partial strings in the Meaning column, you need to take this into account.